# not always same result with fileReader Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, input, filereader

I am using fileReader for checking if a profile picture uploaded matches with my conditions. However, i don't have always the same result. Can you help me to fix that bug ?

Here my htlm code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>File API</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">

        <h1>Image File Reader</h1>
        <div>
            Select an image file: 
            <input type="file" id="fileInput">
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="images.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here my javascript/fileReader (images.js) code:

```
window.onload = function() 
{
    var width=0;
    var height=0;
    var exten= false;
    var size = false;

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');


    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) 
    {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var imageType = /image.png/;

        if (file.type.match(imageType)) 
        {
            exten = true;
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) 
            {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;

                img.onload = function()
                {
                    width=this.width;
                    height=this.height;
                }
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            exten= false;
        }

        if(width == 50 && height ==50)
        {
            size = true;
        }
        else
        {
            size = false;
        }

        //Here, we check that the image matches with png and 50*50px
        if(size && exten)
        {
            alert('Your image is ok.');
        }
        else
        {
            if(!size && !exten)
            {
                alert('Image needs to be 50*50px and in png');
            }
            else
            {
                if(!size && exten)
                {
                    alert('Image needs to be 50*50px');
                }
                else
                {
                    if(size && !exten)
                    {
                        alert('Image needs to be in png');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You've to wait the execution of the `img.onload` event before checking `width` and `height`.

The code that's outside that event handler and that uses those properties should be moved inside it.